# Changing /etc/hosts not getting affected

Tags: macos, network, dns

I have added the following line in my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   myapp.corp.com
```

so my full `/etc/hosts` looks like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   myapp.corp.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

After this, I have run the following commands:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

After which I have started the local server, but

```
myapp.corp.com:8080
```

is not working. Where as `localhost:8080` works. I tried even restarting my machine, clearing the browser cache. Nothing helped.

Where I'm making mistake?

Comment: Did you edit that file as root?  Open the file up again to make sure your changes took hold.  Making that edit works on my machine without having to flush anything.

Comment: Yes as a root only I have edited the file.

Comment: Try dig or ping that domain to see what your OS think its IP address is.